# How can I include listView in a layout with other views in the layout already

Tags: java, android

I have  an activity with `ImageView` on top and `TextView` in bottom. I want to add a `ListView` in between, How can i do that?

Comment: please share the code , and where is your problem in the code

Comment: Share your xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Take linear layout as parent layout and give its orientation vertical. Add imageview, listview, textview sequentially. Now provide weight to listview as 1 and its height as 0dp. Providing weight 1 to listview will allow it to spread in the whole empty space of the layout. Hope this helps

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Correctly explained. But for OP you need to add your xml file code too so it will be better for OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) as parent and a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) instead of ListView.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textview"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```